# ADODB.Connection slow on one pc fast on another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba project on an excel file and two identical laptops.

The office installation on both laptops is 64bit.

On the 1st laptop the execution of the below code takes 20 seconds and on the second laptop takes ages.

I searched a lot but did not find what is causing the issue.

Any suggestions are welcome.

The code is

```
    Sub GetDataFromADO()
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    'Turn of Automatic calculation'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
    
    
        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        Worksheets("Data").Rows(8 & ":" & Worksheets("Data").Rows.Count).Delete
    
    
            Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
            Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
            Dim strSQL As String
    
            objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Database;User ID=user;Password=pass;"
            objMyConn.Open
    
        'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
            strSQL = "select * from table where date>= DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE())-1,0) order by column1, column2"
    
        'Open Recordset'
            Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
            objMyRecordset.Open strSQL
    
        'Copy Data to Excel'
            ActiveSheet.Range("A8").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
        'Create Index for lookups'
        'Find Last Row'
            Dim Lastrow As Long
            Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'Copy Formula Until the last row'
            Range("AG8:AG" & Lastrow).Formula = "=E8&F8"
    ErrorHandler:
    'Turn on Automatic calculation'
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Try closing your recordset and connection after use - that should also be your default error handler. You never want outlying connections hanging around (slowing things down)..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using breakpoints through out the code to pinpoint the problem. From your sample I would add one at the if line, on the strSQL line, on the Activesheet line, and on the Range("AG8 line. This will help you narrow down where the issue is and help you focus on what the problem could be. Outside of the program itself, compare the hardware in the computers. Look at CPU, RAM, and since you have active connections, how they are connected to the internet.

Answer (score -1):

Ι uninstalled office465 and reinstalled it and the problem is gone, I haven't figured what was the issue.